# How to add progressbar for downloading image IOS7

Tags: ios, image, uiprogressview

Hi in application i have image in my `UIImageView` i want to download the image and saving in the `photolibrary`. Now i want to show the downloading progress to the user and give the alert message image saved in `photolibrary` please tell how to achieve this one.

My image save code.

```
- (IBAction)down:(id)sender {

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageview.image, nil, nil, nil);

 }
```

I have used the above code to save the image photolibrary please tell me how to add the `UIProgressView` by clicking button

Comment: I'm unsure if the default UIProgressView supports such feature, but you could take a look at MBProgressHUD and SVProgressHUD. They are open source and very easy to create/display such HUDs.

Comment: @LordZsolt can u please provide me url link for the progressbar

Comment: https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD and https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD